# Counting Nonzero Entries per Class in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am working through the Naive Bayes Classifier examples in the book ‘Introduction to Machine Learning with Python’ and am struggling to understand the mechanics of the following code example:

```
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[0,1,0,1],
              [1,0,1,1],
              [0,0,0,1],
              [1,0,1,0]])

y = np.array([0,1,0,1])

print(X)
print('\n')
print(y)
print('\n')

counts = {}

for label in np.unique(y):
    print(label,'\n')
    counts[label] = X[y == label].sum(axis=0)
    print(counts[label],'\n')

print('Feature counts:\n{}'.format(counts))
```

**Output of code**:

```
[[0 1 0 1]
 [1 0 1 1]
 [0 0 0 1]
 [1 0 1 0]]


[0 1 0 1]


0 

[0 1 0 2] 

1 

[2 0 2 1] 

Feature counts:
{0: array([0, 1, 0, 2]), 1: array([2, 0, 2, 1])}
```

I do not understand how the arrays for each class (0 and 1) are being populated.

My understanding is that sum(axis=0) means summing down a column of a matrix. Therefore for the “0” label (aka class) I count the following in the matrix ‘X’:

2 zeros in the first column, 3 zeros in the second column, 2 zeroes in the third column, 1 zero in the fourth column

Given the code output my understanding is clearly not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to forget the Boolean mask `y == label`.

The documentation about [Boolean or “mask” index arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html) states:

> Unlike in the case of integer index arrays, in the boolean case, the result is a 1-D array containing all the elements in the indexed array corresponding to all the true elements in the boolean array.

Therefore `X[y == label]` for `label = 0` results in:

```
X[np.array(true, false, true, false)]
```

Which according to the doc, is:

```
[[0 1 0 1]
 [0 0 0 1]]
```

Sum vertically and you get:

```
count[0] = np.array([0, 1, 0, 2])
```

The same process gets `count[1]`. This time `label = 1`, `y == label` gives `np.array(false, true, false, true)`. Masking `X` with this array gives:

```
[[1 0 1 1]
 [1 0 1 0]]
```

Sum vertically to obtain:

```
count[1] = np.array([2, 0, 2, 1])
```

Answer (score 2):

You may start from the inner part of the codeline

```
X[y == label].sum(axis=0)
```

Let's look at the case `label==0`. Then

```
y == label
# results in
[ True False  True False]
```

Using this boolean list with 4 entries to index `X` will hence select the first and third row from X,

```
[[0 1 0 1]   # True
 [1 0 1 1]   # False
 [0 0 0 1]   # True
 [1 0 1 0]]  # False
```

```
X[y == label]
#results in
[[0 1 0 1]
 [0 0 0 1]]
```

Now you sum along the column direction of this 2x4 array

```
X[y == label].sum(axis=0)
# results in
[0 1 0 2]
```

I'm guessing here, but what you probably want to do is create a boolean array of `X` itself and sum over its columns.

```
counts[label] = (X == label).sum(axis=0)
```

Running the code with this line will produce

```
# for label == 0
[2 3 2 1] 
# for label == 1
[2 1 2 3]
```